# Cyclic inequality, need help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, quadratics

$x+\frac{1}{y}=10$; 
$y+\frac{1}{z}=10$;
$z+\frac{1}{x}=10$;

What is the highest possible value of z?

Comment: Are you missing a $10$ in front of $x$ at the beginning?And what have you tried

Comment: No, I am not missing it, I know these kind of inequalities need a special way of solution, but I don't quite remember it

Comment: are they positive reals or what are they?

Comment: prove that follows from the System $$x=y=z$$

Comment: Why does this question mention inequalities? This looks like system of $3$ equations in $3$ variables.

Answer (score 2):

$x=\frac{1}{10-z}$ and $1=y\left(10-\frac{1}{10-z}\right)$,

which gives $y=\frac{10-z}{99-10z}$.

Hence, $$\frac{(10-z)z}{99-10z}+1=10z$$ or
$$z^2-10z+1=0,$$ which gives the answer: $5+\sqrt{24}$.

Answer (score 0):

As you put it, it's an equation with two solutions. The one with the highest z has $z=5+2\sqrt 6$